# How to configure JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in a single line of code?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I use Jackson for JSON serialisation in a REST application like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyResource1.class);
        classes.add(MyResource2.class);
        ...
        return classes;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        singletons.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(
            SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false)); // (*)
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

(*) Necessary otherwise fields annotated with @XmlElementRef will appear in JSON output as `"myField": null` when null (instead of not appearing), while it's fine for fields annotated with @XmlElement.

However the use of `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES` is deprecated in favor of `SerializationConfig.setSerializationInclusion(..)` (1)
which itself is deprecated in favor of `SerializationConfig.withSerializationInclusion(..)` or *configure through ObjectMapper* (2)

But what I think is done using `new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(..)` is indeed configuring an ObjectMapper (I took a look at the code).

So my question is: how do I configure this properly without using any deprecated property and without (re)creating new config class(es)?

(1) http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.Feature.html#WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES

(2) http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.html#setSerializationInclusion(org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion)

Answer (score 5):

I use next config and OM:

```
public class JaxbJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public JaxbJacksonObjectMapper() {
        configure(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false); // IMPORTANT must be false
        configure(Feature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, true);
        configure(Feature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, true);
        configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();

        super.getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.ALWAYS);
        super.getDeserializationConfig()
                .withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        super.getSerializationConfig()
                .withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);

    }

}
```

Hopes it help

UPD:
Sorry, I forgot about next part. Also you need to register it, like:

```
@Provider
public final class ReContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;

    public ReContextResolver() throws Exception {
        jacksonObjectMapper = new JaxbJacksonObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> objectType) {
        return jacksonObjectMapper;
    }

}
```

You can combine it in one class, as for me — I use POJO mapping and direct parsing, so for me its better.

Comment: Finally I still don't get what you do with this new `ContextResolver`?

Comment: I use Spring, this ContextResolver should be just under contact(scanned package). This ContextResolver register(and replace default) ObjectMapper

Comment: You forgot to say that the class should have a Spring annotation (I chose `@Component`) to be auto-registered by Spring. Thanks btw.

Comment: thanks for your comment @maxxyme , but annotation @ Provider is enough.